# Compilation order and effect of unused files in C++

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, linker, include

In my project I use a bit of third party code like [Vulkan Memory Allocator](https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator) or [STB](https://github.com/nothings/stb), which require to put a define before the first include of their header file. The VMA docu suggests to create an extra file for this purpose, and since I have several such demands, I decided to create a `ThirdPartySetup.cpp` file:

```
#define VOLK_IMPLEMENTATION
#define VK_NO_PROTOTYPES
#include "volk.h"

#define VMA_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "vk_mem_alloc.h"

#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

#define TINYOBJLOADER_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "tiny_obj_loader.h"
```

Now I obviously want to use this. I have a `Renderer` class, which should be what any user uses to start up my project. Also, my project uses CMake.

I have now added my `ThirdPartySetup.cpp` to the `CMakeLists.txt`, such that it also appears in my project when creating a Visual Studio solution, and I've included the `ThirdPartySetup.cpp` in my `Renderer.cpp` (right after the class's own header include, but the order probably doesn't matter for my problem):

```
#include "Renderer.h"
#include "ThirdPartySetup.cpp"

// ... more includes

Renderer::Renderer(){...}
```

When compiling this, I get LNK 2005 linker errors for ThirdPartySetup.cpp about third party stuff already being defined in Renderer.obj. My assumption therefore is: Visual Studio compiles Renderer first, and then ThirdPartySetup. If I were to not use these defines (i.e. delete the `ThirdPartySetup.cpp` file, I get a compilation error from VMA about having to put the defines before including vulkan.
However, if I simply let the `ThirdPartySetup.cpp` file exist in the project without ever using it anywhere, it gets compiled without errors.
I'd be satisfied with that, but I doubt this is safe to do as the compilation error is (afaik) not guaranteed to always compile ThirdPartySetup before anything else.

Therefore my questions are (apart from the obvious "How to fix this"):

1. Can I ensure compilation order somehow to avoid problems in the future?
2. Can I use a file like my `ThirdPartySetup.cpp` as an include without it being compiled at all? I read somewhere (TM) that CMake only compiles files that have some sort of c++ extension, but just renaming my file to `ThirdPartySetup.txt` "feels" wrong.
3. What effects do files have that are compiled but not used anyway? It looks like the `#define` macros are used even though the file is not

Comment: "Compilation order and effect of unused files in C++" - *Compilation order* usually shouldn't matter, but *linking order* can matter a great deal.

Comment: If that `VOLK_IMPLEMENTATION` macro means what it seems to suggest, it's telling the `volk.h` header to define the implementation of all of its functions and not just the declarations. When you `#include` that file it's just like writing `void f() {}` in a header; you'll get a definition of that function in every source file that includes that header. So don't `#include` that file anywhere; it's a source file, and should be compiled by itself, just like the code that you write.

Comment: @Jesper Juhl: Since I got a linker error, that is probably correct.

Comment: @Pete Becker: The requirements of (at least some of) these third party libs was to set the defines before the first include. I tried to ensure this through this include.

Comment: I'll bet that those requirements tell you to do that in exactly one place, not in every place where you use the header.

Comment: Yes they do. That's why I wanted to do it once in the central Renderer before any actual logic (and thus includes of their files) happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you created is used both a source and a header file, at the same time. That will not work, all source files ([*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))) that include it will have the definitions and implementations, as well as the source file itself if you try to build it as a source file.

Instead build it as a normal source file, and do *not* include it anywhere. Only include the actual header files, when and where they are needed.

Comment: Naming it `.cpp` stems from my confusion from VMA, saying `In exactly one CPP file define following macro before this include.` I assumed they literally meant .cpp file. It works with the file as header (i.e. renaming it to `ThirdPartySetup.h` and including it that way), but I'm still curiours about my questions 1 and 3. I will have to read up on translation units though.